# SQL: How to model multiple n:m relations in ERM

Tags: sql, eer-model

I have a scenario where I have risks that can occur in many other Entities as in Organizational Units,  as depicted in the image below. Is there a best practice for modeling in this scenario or is the modeling I have chosen a good practice?

[image: multiple n:m relations]

Comment: Based on what you've written it seems correct to me, cross join tables are the traditional way to deal with what you've written.